# why i hear sound in fan?

Tags: ac, inverter, induction-motor

I have a table fan which runs on 220v ac mains when we power the fan it works normally, but when power cuts off(frequently occurs in India), then the ups inverter supplies the power, then the fan makes some strange sound. why? whats the reason for weird sound?

Comment: `strange sound` ... please describe the sound ... if you have never seen a dog in your life, then a dog's bark would be a "weird sound"

Comment: Or record the sound and provide a link.

Answer (score 8):

What UPS inverter is used?

If it is a model that does not produce a "proper" sinewave signal then this distorted sinewave can be the issue.

Cheap inverters just use "hard" switching and a transformer to turn the battery power into something that looks like mains power. This hard switching means that the sinewave isn't very "clean". This means that it contains not only the 50 Hz or 60 Hz of the sinewave itself but also lots of harmonics, multiples of 50 or 60 Hz which are **very audible**. The fan's motor also works a bit as a loudspeaker (be it an inefficient one) so the harmonics on the mains signal are also turned into sounds.

Human ears aren't that sensitive to low frequencies so on real mains power the 50 or 60 Hz isn't such an issue as you don't hear it so well. The harmonics can easily be up to kHz range which human ears do hear very well.

"Pure sinewave" or "true sinewave" inverters use more complex electronics to make the generated mains look more like the real mains signal, containing only the 50 or 60 Hz and few harmonics. At least a lot less harmonics compared to using the "hard switching" inverter.

Obviously the "Pure sinewave" or "true sinewave" inverters are generally a bit more expensive than the traditional "hard" switching type.

In theory a special mains filter (one designed to "clean up" the sinewave from a cheap inverter) could be used to get rid of the sounds but I doubt if such a filter exists, if it will be effective enough and if that would be cost effective compared to a "Pure sinewave" or "true sinewave" inverter.

Comment: To add to this, some inverters generate a square wave which will have all sorts of harmonics and hence the noise. They are slowly being replaced with sinewave inverters but still a lot of people are using those.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strange sound is a high pitched squeal or whining sound, that is the result of the artificial sine wave created by the UPS. A UPS stores energy  in batteries as DC power. In order to be useful to AC machines (like your table fan), the UPS creates a "pseudo (fake) sine wave" from that DC power. There are several ways to do it, but all of them cause issues within the AC motor itself, varying by the method used and the filtering provided. The cheaper the UPS, the less attention to those details is taken, resulting in varying degrees of audible noises made by your AC motor.

Most of the noise is the result of "magnetostriction" in the laminated steel core parts in the motor reacting to the pulsed DC nature of the UPS output to make the motor think it is getting AC. Better UPS designs use what's called PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) on the output and by using what's called a "carrier frequency" at a higher rate, the noise can be mitigated. But really it is just making the pitch too high for humans to hear. Cheaper UPS designs use a simpler "square wave" format that is just one large pulse of DC in one direction, then the next, for each sine wave. Others yet use a "stepped wave" format. All of them however can cause varying degrees of motor noise.

Because the motor noise also has to do with the quality of the motor construction, a cheap motor will make more noise than a better one as well.

It's generally harmless though.